# Saas With ExtJS + Spring + MySQL

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, saas, multi-tenant

We have an idea of developing a SaaS application using below technology.

**Frontend HTML5 UI Framework** - ExtJS
**Backend Application** - Spring + JPA
**Database** - MySQL

Please clarify on below things.

1. Considering the fact 'Modern web application should be stateless' for scaling purpose how do i manage sessions in this case?
2. Is Spring Security is mature enough to support SaaS applications.
3. Being a SaaS application I need to have lot of customization per tenant(i.e Display custom fields in forms, Display custom column in tables). What is the recommended approach to achieve this?
4. I need different look and feel of application based on type of user logged in. Say I need to display/hide a tab based on user role. How to achieve this? Should these roles need to be downloaded to browser and toggle UI elements based on user role?
5. I choose to go with separate schema Multitenancy. Is Hibernate is way to go or I can go with any JPA(EclipseLink)?
6. Any other technology limitations which i need to aware of with this combination.

Any input will be helpful.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

1: I reject the premise that "Modern web application should be stateless" and I would like to see some citations for that statement. You can achieve scalability in a statefull application same as you can build a stateless application that doesn't scale at all.

2: It's more a question of "is it mature enough for commercial applications?" and I would say yes, it is. Depending on the actual requirements of your application, it may or may not be suited, but that has less to do with maturity than features.

3: Hard to say based on the very limited information provided. Anything from creating custom view instances (jsps, velocity-files, JSF2 views or which ever view technology you use) to dynamic, database-driven views to a full-blown CMS platform.

4: See answer 3 above. I general though, you build views in such a way that elements a user is not authorized to view are not rendered. Spring-security has taglibs for this type of functionality

5: Again, not enough information. Hibernate 4 ostensibly has support for multitenancy, but you will have to verify that it fulfills your particular requirements. AFAIK, there is no concept of multitenancy in the JPA standard (yet).

6: No doubt, but can't say what based on the information you provided. There are no inherent incompatibilities between the technologies you mention, but there are always limitations. Spring can't make coffee. JPA is lousy at driving your kids to school.